# How can I write a regex in Java that will perform a .replaceFirst on a group that is not in a comment?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

So I need to return modified String where it replaces the first instance of a token with another token while skipping comments.  Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
This whole quote is one big String
-- I don't want to replace this @@
But I want to replace this @@!
```

Being a former .NET developer, I thought this was easy.  I'd just do a negative lookbehind like this:

```
(?<!--.*)@@
```

But then I learned Java can't do this.  So upon learning that the curly braces are okay, I tried this:

```
(?<!--.{0,9001})@@
```

That didn't throw an exception, but it did match the @@ in the comment.

When I test this regex with a Java regex tester, it works as expected.  About the only thing I can think of is that I'm using Java 1.5.  Is it possible that Java 1.5 has a bug in its regex engine?  Assuming it does, how do I get Java 1.5 to do what I want it to do without breaking up my string and reassembling it?

**EDIT** I changed the # to the -- operator since it looks like the regex will be more complex with two chars instead of one.  I originally did not reveal that I was modifying a query in order to avoid off topic discussion on "Well you shouldn't modify queries that way!"  I have a very good reason for doing this.  Please don't discuss query modification good practices.  Thanks

Comment: So you want to replace `@@` in the 3rd example and not in the 2nd one?

Comment: In Java regex, you can't give "finitely-many" length or regex with unclear length to the look-behind. Some languages even restrict it more to fixed length regex in look-behind. .NET is the only one I know that support arbitrary length look-behind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really don't need a `negative look-behind` here. You can do it without that too.

It would be like this:

```
String str = "I don't want to replace this @@";     
str = str.replaceAll("^([^#].*?)@@", "$1");
```

So, it replaces first occurrence of `@@` in the string that does not start with `#` with the part of the string before `@@`. So, `@@` is removed. Here `replaceAll` works because it uses a *reluctant quantifier* - `.*?`. So, it will automatically stop at the first `@@`.

---

As correctly pointed out by @nhahtdh in the comment, that this might fail, if your comment is at the end of the line. So, you can rather use this one:

```
String str = "I don't want to # replace this @@";
str = str.replaceAll("^([^#]*?)@@", "$1");
```

This one will work for any case. And in the given example case, it won't replace the `@@`, as it is a part of the comment.

---

If your comment start is denoted by two characters, then negated character class won't work. You would need to use `negative look-ahead` like this:

```
String str = "This whole quote @@  is one big String -- asdf @@\n" +
             "-- I don't want to replace this @@\n" + 
             "But I want to replace this @@!";
str = str.replaceAll("(?m)^(((?!--).)*?)@@", "$1");

System.out.println(str);
```

**Output:**

```
This whole quote   is one big String -- asdf @@
-- I don't want to replace this @@
But I want to replace this !
```

`(?m)` at the beginning of the pattern is used to enable `MULTILINE` mode of matching, so the `^` will match the start of each line, rather than the start of the entire expression.

Comment: The only problem that this may have is in one line: `some text here #comment @@`. Not sure whether this may happen.

Comment: @nhahtdh. Yeah, that will be a problem. Let's see how I can modify the regex. Nice catch :)

Comment: I made a change to my question since I'm actually using two chars for the comment start rather than one.  How would this change the regex?

Comment: Thanks, Rohit.  This seems to replace the whole line rather than just the @@.  Here's what I pasted into my eclipse Display tab:
"This whole quote @@ is one big String -- asdf @@\n-- I don't want to replace this @@\nButI want to replace this@@!".replaceAll("(?m)^(((?!--).)*?)@@", "foo")

Comment: I'm using Java 1.5 (not by choice) by the way.  I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: So, what output did you got?

Comment: Actually, you didn't used `$1` in the replacement string. Try : `.replaceAll("(?m)^(((?!--).)*?)@@", "$1foo")`` in that.

Comment: `"This whole quote @@ is one big String -- asdf @@\n-- I don't want to replace this @@\nButI want to replace this@@!".replaceAll("(?m)^(((?!--).)*?)@@", "$1foo");`

Comment: @JasonThompson. Remember to mark the answer as accepted, if of course your issue is resolved.

Comment: Ah... of course... The capture result. Thank you for your patience and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
String string = "This whole quote is one big String\n" +
                "# I don't want to replace this @@\n" +
                "And I also # don't want to replace this @@\n" +
                "But I want to replace this @@!\n" +
                "But not this @@!";

Matcher m =
    Pattern.compile (
        "^((?:[^@#]|@[^@]|#[^\n]*)*)@@", Pattern.MULTILINE).
            matcher (string);

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer ();
if (m.find ())
    m.appendReplacement (result, "$1FOO");
m.appendTail (result);

System.out.println (result.toString ());
```